# Internet speed capped at 100 mbits on Realtek PCIe Family Controller, until I manually replug the cable

Tags: windows-10, networking, ethernet, network-adapter, gigabit-ethernet

Basically, until I unplug and plug back my cable, I'm stuck at a 100 mbit connection. Replugging it fixes the issue, but I'd hate to do this every time I start up my computer.

Could someone please share some insights as to what I can do to fix this?

I've just downloaded the latest drivers for Realtek PCIe Family Controller on Windows 10.

I've also tried removing Auto-Negotiation and various other settings like Power savings mode and what-not to no avail.

I searched over the internet for workarounds, but most people are stuck trying to identify if they even support a gigabit connection, whereas I clearly do - it's just a funky glitch requiring manual labor to "fix".

Comment: Does this happen after booting up the PC or do you use standby or hibernate mode? Windows 10 has a built-in partial hibernate functionality called "fast startup". You can try to disable it and see if it solved your problem.

Comment: @Robert after booting up the PC. The funny thing is that after I've done it once - changing any settings on my device (like for example changing from auto negotiation to 1000 full duplex) will still connect with the proper speed (1Gbps)

Comment: What I would do is get a good (high) quality USB 3 Ethernet Adapter and see if the speed is reliable between restarts.

Comment: @Robert disabling my Fast Boot option from the BIOS made it possible to restart my computer without having to unplug my cable. I'll let you know tomorrow if the problem has fully been fixed. Thank you!

Comment: Fastboot Isa Windows 10 option, a similar named option in your BIOS should be something different.

Comment: @Robert I couldn't find the fast boot in windows 10, I'll try to dig around. Sadly the problem still exists - it required manual unplugging and re-plugging of the cable. I guess I don't support Fast boot by the looks of it?

Comment: As I wrote it is called "fast start" not "fast boot". This site shows how to enable fast start (while you want to disable it) https://lifehacker.com/enable-this-setting-to-make-windows-10-boot-up-faster-1743697169

Comment: @Robert Yeah, I've been trying up until now to make that option pop up, and it finally did - it seems I completely have disable hibernation on my computer. Enabling it with `powercfg.exe /hibernate on` made the option available. I disabled it. Shut down my computer. And voila - we are back to square one. It seems this is not the cause. I'll be disabling hibernation again completely now - I don't think Fast startup can work without it, as you explained.